# Grails How to call service from static method of domain class?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a static method on my domain class, and want to get all the business logic out of the domain class definition into the service, but I can't call the service in the domain class static method since the service itself is defined on the instance not the domain class.

What the best solve for this?

E.g.

```
class Foo {
   def fooService
   Integer count =0
   String name

   static void updateFoo(String name) {
      def foo = FindByName(name)
      fooService.beforeUpdateProcess(foo)   //fooService unavailable here  
      foo.count+=1
      foo.save()
   }
```

}

Comment: I'm thinking that beforeUpdateProcess itself should be a static method of fooService in which case the solution is simply FooService.beforeUpdateProcess(foo).  Is that the right way to handle it?

Comment: I would suggest not using static methods in general, and especially in domains or services.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since services are beans, you would access them the way you would generically access any bean from the application context. Grails has a Holders helper for this.:

```
FooService fooService = grails.util.Holders.applicationContext.getBean('fooService') as FooService
```